# How to tie the first note of the second volta in MuseScore?

Tags: musescore, repeats, ties

How to tie the **(first) note** of the **second volta** to the previous note in MuseScore?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not directly supported. See some discussion here: http://musescore.org/en/node/15720#comment-63654

Some workarounds:
- add the previous measure also into the volta
- use a slur to "fake" a tie

Comment: thanks for the link. I'll check out using a slur and the suggestions given over there.

Comment: Apparently there is no good solution. I didn't figure how to slur them. So the most readable would be to add the previous bar to the first and second voltas. However, in my case I'd even have to add the previous two bars, which makes 4 bars all in all. I think I just leave it until a ms version comes out which supports this.

Answer (score 2):

As of 9 Aug 2022, this remains unsupported directly, but there are several workarounds described to accommodate various scenarios: [How to create ties leading into a 2nd ending](https://musescore.org/en/node/267614)

The workarounds given are:

1. Use special characters (basically, position two ties by hand)
2. Avoid leading ties (rewrite the voltas to include the "problem" measure)
3. Use invisible grace notes
4. Use invisible ties (from the last note of volta 1 to the first note of volta 2)
5. Use invisible voice and ties (similar to #4, but using a second voice)

The image below was created by applying a "laissez vibrer" articulation mark (see the blue box) to the first note of the second volta, then shifting it left by hand.

[image: Tie into first note of 2nd ending]

Comment: I think the invisible grace note provides the best playback given that the ending note of the 1st volta does not match the starting note of the 2nd volta, which matches the first time I had to use a workaround (that wasn't avoiding the leading tie in the first place; avoiding that tie doesn't quite work when the measure before the voltas is 16th note-filled).